# Dropdown remains empty -populating with json data

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json

Hi im populating dropdown on change event of another dropdown from sql server using json data,
I got json data when i checked in firefox 
but still my dropdown remains empty
Could somebody please help me what im doing wrong here 
here is my code

```
   function OnCathwordPopulated(response) {

         var xx = (typeof response.d) == 'string' ? eval('(' + response.d + ')') : response.d;

         $("#<%=ddlCatchword.ClientID %>").removeAttr("disabled");

         $("#<%=ddlCatchword.ClientID %>").children().remove();

         $("#<%=ddlCatchword.ClientID %>").empty().append("<option selected='selected' value='0'>Please select</option>");

         var listItems = "";
         for (var i = 0; i < xx.length; i++) {

             var val1 = xx[i];

             var text1 = xx[i];
             listItems += "<option value='" + val1+ "'>" + text1 + "</option>";


         } $("#<%=ddlCatchword.ClientID%>").html(listItems);


     }
```

I used another method also 
here is

```
             $("#<%=ddlCatchword.ClientID%>").append($("<option></option>").val(val1).text(text));
```

Comment: Is it possible that your are spelling the function name wrong? You have `OnCathwordPopulated` and you might be calling `OnCatchwordPopulated`. (note the 'c') Check your debugger for JavaScript errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it solved by using following trick,

```
 $("#<%=ddlCatchword.ClientID%>").html(listItems); $("#<%=ddlCatchword.ClientID%>").selectmenu('refresh', true);
```

Got it working with the help from http://ozkary.blogspot.no/2010/12/jquery-mobile-select-controls-populated.html
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Modded the code to remove properly. I'm assuming this is selecting the correct list based off the code above. Also, a fiddle for example: http://jsfiddle.net/Tkt2B/

```
$("#<%=ddlCatchword.ClientID %>").removeAttr("disabled");
$("#<%=ddlCatchword.ClientID %>").find("option").remove().end()
$("#<%=ddlCatchword.ClientID %>").append("<option selected='selected' value='0'>Please select</option>");

 var listItems = "";
 for (var i = 0; i < xx.length; i++) {
     var val1 = xx[i];
     var text1 = xx[i];
     listItems += "<option value='" + val1+ "'>" + text1 + "</option>";
 } 

 $("#<%=ddlCatchword.ClientID%>").append(listItems);
```

Comment: @Sonali Editted the asnwer, want to try it again?

Comment: @sonali Tried revamping a little more, let me know.

Comment: No still same problem...   

I have tried this method to test out json data

var h = ' <select name="test" id="ss" class="country" data-native-menu="false">';
             h = h + listItems;
             var w = window.open(); $(w.document.body).html(h);

And it opens new dropdwon with all json data in new window.. I dont know what strange thing is wrong ... please note im using jquery mobile using asp.net

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this method to test out data

```
var h = ' <select name="test" id="ss" class="country" data-native-menu="false">';
             h = h + listItems;
             var w = window.open(); $(w.document.body).html(h);
```

And it opens new dropdwon with all json data in new window..
I dont know what strange thing is wrong ... 
please note im using jquery mobile using asp.net